# What does the integer shown in typeid().name() mean?

Tags: c++, typeid

What does the integer shown in the output of `typeid().name()` mean? For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

class implementer{
public :
    void forNameSake()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    implementer imp2;
    std::cout<<typeid(imp2).name();
}
```

Gives the output:

> 11implementer

What does the `11` in the output mean?

Comment: The length of the identifier that follows. This is compiler specific though.

Comment: Thank you, so you mean some compilers don't show the value?

Comment: No, I mean the format of the string is an implementation detail of the compiler. Theoretically a different compiler could yield "HelloWorld" here, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name

Comment: `name` is not very useful. Sometimes you get an inscrutable hash. It doesn't even guarantee that the name will be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the 11 in the output mean?

*In this particular case, most probably* it means the length of the identifier that follows. `implementer` is 11 characters.

You might be interested in https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangle.name, specifically in the `<source-name> ::= <positive length number> <identifier>` part.